# Is it time to "branch" the twitter-bootstrap tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The Bootstrap folks [released RC1 of version 3 on July 27, 2013](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/07/27/bootstrap-3-rc1/). As I've perused the documentation, it's become clear that v3+ will incorporate some serious departures from earlier versions of the Bootstrap project, **to the point that answers to pre-Bootstrap3 questions will not work in Bootstrap 3+.**

For example, an inline unordered list previously mandated using the "inline" class: `<ul class="inline">`. Now that same styling requires the "list-inline" class: `<ul class="list-inline">`. The scaffolding nomenclature [has changed from "spanX"](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) to ["col-X"](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) (though it's even more complicated than that when you get into it, still, "span" is no more).

How should this be addressed? Is it time to "branch" the twitter-bootstrap tag?

**Another issue** to consider while we're addressing these tag names: [the guys who develop Bootstrap no longer work for Twitter](http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2012/09/29/onward/). So the 'twitter-' part of the [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag (the part that used to distinguish it from the [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) tag) is no longer applicable.

Comment: While `twitter-` might not be applicable anymore, it doesn't sound like [tag:bootstrap] will be applicable either. Do you have a proposed replacement?

Comment: I don't understand why people keep saying that Bootstrap 3 has been released. I've been looking everywhere but all I find is a release *candidate*. They're even planning more than one RC, so it'll be a few weeks before Bootstrap 3 is actually released.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I just checked the link, it explicitly says there will be more RCs: `Today we're releasing the first of at least two release candidates for Bootstrap 3...`.

Comment: @thegrinner: no, I can't think of a single one that would work (besides "Bootstrap", which is already taken). :/

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: are you implying that perhaps the changes in the class names are just temporary/only for the RC and that the actual release will revert the class names to the originals (I'm trying to understand why RC vs full-release should change the course of this discussion)?

Answer (score 10):

I could rename [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) to [bootstrap-framework](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework), for starters.

As for a tag specific to Bootstrap 3, [bootstrap-framework-3](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-framework-3) seems awkwardly long but I'm just as uncertain about [bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-3) because it's still kind of "inconsistent" with the new name, if you know what I mean. Either way I would hold off on creating a version-specific tag at all until the community demonstrates a sufficient need for it.

And when that does happen, somebody else can [create it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) easily and painlessly. Besides, I already have [dibs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=106224) on the original [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag even though I've never used the framework at all ever since it was first released. I don't need or wish to be responsible for the creation of another Stack Overflow tag for a framework I don't use ;)

Comment: The rename to [tag:bootstrap-framework] make sense to me, but I'm not convinced the new version merits a new tag. It still has a lot in common and I could point out other whole languages with API/ABI changes that have been more significant that aren't forked. Of course old answers are dated, but so are basic html/css/javascript questions.